# Position Relativelayout

Tags: android

I have a Relative layout which is smaller than the screen's width and height and it is the parent of all the layouts for the Activity. I want to position the relative layout in the center of the screen.

This is what I tried:

```
RelativeLayout mainRL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainDataEntryRelativeLayout);
mainRL.layout(20, 30, 0, 0);
```

But this is not working. Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add the values "center_vertical" and "center_horizontal" to the property "layout_gravity".

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

Comment: Your welcome!!! The property "gravity", it's supposed to be used for the view's content, that why it might not work the other solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` or `<YourRelativeLayout>.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)`
for that `RelativeLayout`